# @CrossOrigin not working in Spring Boot WebFlux

Tags: angular, spring-boot, cors

I tried all possible annotations but still I cant get pass this error on my local host. Both backend and frontend angular is running on localhost. Not sure if this has anything to do with WebFlux. Here is my controller class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/userinfo")
//@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
//@CrossOrigin
public class WebController {
    public static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebController.class);
    @Autowired
    private UserInfoService userInfoService;
    
    @GetMapping("/users")
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
    public Flux<UserInfo> getAll() {
        LOG.info("---Beginning of the method---");
        return userInfoService.getAll();
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/id/{userId}")
    public Mono<UserInfo> getByUserId(@PathVariable("userId") Long userId) {
        LOG.info("---Beginning of the method---");
        return userInfoService.getById(userId);
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/email/{email}")
    public Mono<UserInfo> getByEmail(@PathVariable("email") String email) {
        LOG.info("---Beginning of the method---");
        return userInfoService.getByEmail(email);
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/new")
    public Mono<UserInfo> addUser(@RequestBody UserInfo userInfo) {
        LOG.info("---Beginning of the method---");
        return userInfoService.addUser(userInfo);
    }

}
```

Here is my angular method calling this rest service:

```
export class HttpServiceService {
  private baseUrl = "localhost:9095/api/userinfo";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getUsers(): Observable<UserInfo[]> {
    return this.http.get<UserInfo[]>(this.baseUrl + "/users");
  }
}
```

I am not passing any header values. Can this be an issue. Also not using security at my backend. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try enabling `allowHeaders` and `methods` like `@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*", methods="*")`

Comment: unfortunately it did not. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Can you please check press `F12` on browser and check what are the errors in developer console? and were you able to make API call from PostMan?

Comment: Yes it is working in postman. In dev console I could see the CORS policy error.

Comment: Dont know why I am getting negative point, is this because of repeated question ?

Comment: Thank you but no idea why this annotations are not working. Dont know what I am missing here. It did work before though. Restarted multiple times. But still the same error!